# Biber and Biblatex: Reference within the Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I have a problem, where all my googeling has left me standing alone.
Currently I am preparing my thesis and I am using biblatex in conjunction with biber.

When dealing with the entrytype `set` everything worked quite well. Now the following Problem has occurred: I am citing a book first and thereafter this book shall be part of a `set`, where I can add an comment to this and some other references.
For example:

> Here is where the book is cited.[foo]
>   Some other Text, with some more citations.[baz,biz,buz]
>   Then some more text and reference to a set of references.[foobar]

Now the bibliography should show like this:

> [foo]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [baz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [biz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [buz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [foobar]  a) [foo] b) a comment c) The Author, The Title... (of [bar1]) d) The Author, The Title... (of [bar2]) d) ...

Apparently this is not possible, as the output changes automatic to citing members of the set:

> Here is where the book is cited.[foobar-a]
>   Some other Text, with some more citations.[baz,biz,buz]
>   Then some more text and reference to a set of references.[foobar]

and the bibliography:

> [baz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [biz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [buz]     The Author, The Title...
>
> [foobar]  a) The Author, The Title... (of [foo]) b) a comment c) The Author, The Title... (of [bar1]) d) The Author, The Title... (of [bar2]) d) ...

I know one can work-around this problem with creating `misc` type entries, where the note command references the actual book:

```
@MISC{foo-ref,
  note = {\cite{foo}}
}
```

and including these into the set. I could work with that, but I would rather find a more elegant solution.

Browsing the biblatex manual I couldn't find an option which completes my goal, or maybe I missed it (It is kind of huge.)

Therefore I would be very grateful if anyone has a better solution.

**Edit:**
Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  title = {Foo},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3000},
  author = {the Foo},
}

@ARTICLE{baz,
  author = {the Baz},
  title = {Baz},
  journal = {J. of Baz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22},
}

@ARTICLE{buz,
  author = {the Buz},
  title = {Buz},
  journal = {J. of Buz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22},
}

@MISC{comment,
  note = {a comment},
}

@BOOK{bar,
  title = {Bar},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3002},
  author = {the Bar},
}

@SET{foobar,
  entryset = {foo,comment,bar},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,final]{scrreprt}               

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                      

\usepackage[german=quotes
           ]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            sorting=none,
            style=numeric-comp,
            style=chem-angew,
            subentry=true,
            maxcitenames=5,mincitenames=4,
            maxbibnames=99,
            backref=true,
            natbib=true
            ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is where the book is cited.\autocite{foo}
Some other Text, with some more citations.\autocite{baz,buz} 

Then some more text and reference to a set of references.\autocite{foobar}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

That results in attached picture (top). With the workaround I get what I want (bottom). But this is clearly not an elegant solution as one can see with the backreferences, which are pointing to the bibliography entry of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJQnD.jpg). (But I could live with that.)
[image]

Comment: A MWE would help. Instead of entry sets, the related entries feature introduced in biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0 might be more appropriate here.

Comment: I have added a MWE. @Audrey I have as you suggested looked at the related entries option. I am a little surprised I overlooked that. But it would not solve the problem completely as I still need another key. What it clearly makes better is that the backreference is correct. But what it does not is, that it compresses all the data to [1] (or again i missed something).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biber-only related entries feature was introduced to biblatex 2.0. It provides a flexible way to group entries. The default output is similar to that of entry sets with `subentry` disabled, but it can be customized via the `relatedtype` field. This field specifies the localization string, formatting directive and bibliography macro used to set the entries given in the `related` field. In the example below a new `relatedtype` key called `set` is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,backref,subentry,citetracker]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

% Access internal back-reference command
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mkbibbackref}[1]{\blx@backref{#1}}
\makeatother

% Customize output for related entries of the type set
\newbibmacro*{related:set}[1]{%
  \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
    {\printtext[parens]{\alph{bbx:relatedcount}}%
     \printunit*{\addnbspace}}
    {}%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \ifentryseen{\thefield{clonesourcekey}}
      {\entrydata{\thefield{clonesourcekey}}{%
         \mkbibbackref{\thefield{entrykey}}%
         \printtext[brackets]{\printfield{prefixnumber}\printfield{labelnumber}}}}
      {\usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% Move back-references for related entries of the type set to the end of the item
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{set}
    {\renewcommand*{\relateddelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
     \savelist*{pageref}{\savedpageref}%
     \clearlist{pageref}}
    {}}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \restorelist{pageref}{\savedpageref}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \finentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  title = {Foo},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3000},
  author = {the Foo}}
@ARTICLE{baz,
  author = {the Baz},
  title = {Baz},
  journal = {J. of Baz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22}}
@ARTICLE{buz,
  author = {the Buz},
  title = {Buz},
  journal = {J. of Buz},
  year = {3001},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {22}}
@MISC{comment,
  note = {a comment}}
@BOOK{bar,
  title = {Bar},
  publisher = {the Press},
  year = {3002},
  author = {the Bar}}
@MISC{foobar,
  related = {foo,comment,bar},
  relatedtype = {set}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is where the book is first cited.\autocite{foo} \clearpage
Reference to a set of references.\autocite{foobar} \clearpage
More citations.\autocite{baz,buz} \clearpage
Another citation to the book.\autocite{foo}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output of each related entry is customized by the new `related:set` bibliography macro. It prints the related entry counter ("(a)", "(b)", etc.) when `subentry` is enabled and, depending on the entry's citation status, either the entry's numeric label or its "verbose" label given by `\usedriver`.

When the related entry set `foobar` is cited, three `bbl` entries are generated for `foo`, `comment` and `bar`. These entries are "cloned" and given new hash-generated entry keys to avoid conflict with direct citations. So the `bbl` file here has two separate entries for `foo` - one generated by a citation directly to `foo` and a second arising from the citation to `foobar`. The original key for a cloned entry is provided by the field `clonesourcekey`, which was introduced to biblatex 2.6.

Note that the new `related:set` provides subentry-like numbers, but these are not accessible via the citation label numbers; individual related entries will have to be cited directly as with the entry `foo` above.

Comment: I really like your solution, unfortunately it introduces something I cannot resolve myself. If you compare entry sets [1-3] with [4], you will notice that the reference 'siehe' is not in parens in [4]. However I could easily live with that. But in every citation after [4] there are additional (wrong) pagenumbers as backreferences. I figured out that it has something to do with the `finentry` macro, as if it is uncommented the original behaviour is restored, but backrefs of [4] are missing.

Comment: @Martin Your sample didn't have parentheses, which is why I left them out. For the second problem I forgot an `\undef`. I'll post a fix in a bit.

Comment: I apologize for that. I just noticed that backrefs without parentheses is the default behaviour for citing a set. I totally overlooked that. Thank you very much for your coding, it is now working very well.

Comment: @Martin No problem. Now that I think of it, the `\undef` business is unnecessary if the back-references are saved locally instead of globally. I'll make one last edit to address that.